# Writing clear jquery code

Tags: jquery

I have a html page with multiple buttons which all execute a jquery ajax code. At the moment I have created a click event handler for every button, but is there any cleaner method?

```
$(function() {
    $("#btn_id_1").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'url1',
            type: 'POST',
            ...
        }
    }
    $("#btn_id_2").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'url2',
            type: 'POST',
            ...
        }
    }
    $("#btn_id_3").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'url2',
            type: 'POST',
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks,
Dennis

Comment: Is only URL different?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use data attributes and unobstrucive javascript:

Html example:

```
<button class="my-class" data-ajax-url="url1">My button</button>
<button class="my-class" data-ajax-url="url2">My button</button>
<button class="my-class" data-ajax-url="url3">My button</button>
<button class="my-class" data-ajax-url="url3">My button</button>
```

Javascript:

```
$(function() {
    $(".my-class").on("click", function() {
         $.ajax({
            url: $(this).data("ajax-url"),
            type: 'POST',
            ...
        })
    });
});
```

Comment: This is best answer yet. Hoping someone post this.

Answer (score 0):

As url for each button are different, then put data attribute for each button like below

```
<input type="button" data-url="url1" id="btn_id_1">
```

You can use comma seperator selector like below :

```
$("#btn_id_1, #btn_id_2, #btn_id_3").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: $(this).data('url'),
            type: 'POST',
            ...
        }
    }
```

OR jQuery [start with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) :

```
 $("[id^=btn_id_]").click(function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: $(this).data('url'),
                type: 'POST',
                ...
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `attribute-selector` is suitable for the context

```
$("[id^='btn_id_']").click(function() {

       var id = this.id; // get id of the current button

        $.ajax({
            url: 'url' + id.split("_")[1],
            type: 'POST',
            ...
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
$("button").click(function (event) {
    var href = event.srcElement.getAttribute("href");
    $.ajax({
        url: href,
        ...
    });
});
```